# virt-install says name is in use, but virsh list --all is empty. Where is virt-install finding this name?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

virt-install says name is in use, but virsh list --all says there is nothing.

```
jrwren@delays:{%22}~ $ virt-install -d -n android -r 512 --disk android.qcow2 -s 4 -c /d/cd\ images/android-x86-2.2-generic.iso --vnc --noautoconsole 
[Thu, 05 Jul 2012 16:57:19 virt-install 23170] DEBUG (cli:220) Launched with command line:
/usr/bin/virt-install -d -n android -r 512 --disk android.qcow2 -s 4 -c /d/cd images/android-x86-2.2-generic.iso --vnc --noautoconsole
[Thu, 05 Jul 2012 16:57:19 virt-install 23170] DEBUG (cli:326) Requesting libvirt URI default
[Thu, 05 Jul 2012 16:57:19 virt-install 23170] DEBUG (cli:328) Received libvirt URI qemu:///session
[Thu, 05 Jul 2012 16:57:20 virt-install 23170] DEBUG (virt-install:259) Requesting virt method 'default', hv type 'default'.
[Thu, 05 Jul 2012 16:57:20 virt-install 23170] DEBUG (virt-install:469) Received virt method 'hvm'
[Thu, 05 Jul 2012 16:57:20 virt-install 23170] DEBUG (virt-install:470) Hypervisor name is 'kvm'
[Thu, 05 Jul 2012 16:57:20 virt-install 23170] DEBUG (cli:950) --graphics compat generated: vnc
[Thu, 05 Jul 2012 16:57:20 virt-install 23170] ERROR (cli:597) Guest name 'android' is already in use.
(venv)jrwren@delays:{%22}~ $ sudo virsh -c qemu:///system list --all
 Id Name                 State
----------------------------------
```

Where is virt-install finding this name?

edit: I should mention that LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI is not set.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using different URI's in each command. Either add `-c qemu:///system` to your `virt-install` command, or change it in your listing to use `qemu:///session`. To undefine use the command `virsh -c qemu:///THECORRECTURI undefine android`.

Comment: thank you. i was confused about session v. system. Now I'm rolling with LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI=qemu:///system

Answer (score 16):

You have to undefined the Virtual Machine. If its running stop it

```
[root@fed18 isos]# virt-install --hvm --name OracleLinux64-1 --ram 2048 --vcpus 1 -f /dev/virtual-machines/OracleLinux64-1 --network bridge=br0 --cdrom /isos/Oracle_Linux_Release_6_Update_4_x86_64.iso --graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0,port=5901 --noautoconsole 
warning: failed to set locale, defaulting to C
ERROR    Guest name 'OracleLinux64-1' is already in use.

root@fed18 ~]# virsh
setlocale: No such file or directory
Welcome to virsh, the virtualization interactive terminal.

Type:  'help' for help with commands
   'quit' to quit
virsh #  undefine OracleLinux64-1
Domain OracleLinux64-1 has been undefined

virsh # quit

[root@fed18 ~]# virt-install --hvm --name OracleLinux64-1 --ram 2048 --vcpus 1 -f /dev/virtual-machines/OracleLinux64-1 --network bridge=br0 --cdrom /isos/Oracle_Linux_Release_6_Update_4_x86_64.iso --graphics vnc,listen=192.168.2.103,port=5901 --noautoconsole 
warning: failed to set locale, defaulting to C

Starting install...
Creating domain...                                                                                                                                          |    0 B  00:00:12     
Domain installation still in progress. You can reconnect to 
the console to complete the installation process.
```

Comment: This worked for me, so thanks! Do you know if it's possible to list all those names that are defined?